# Where is definition of getAuthPassword of user Model in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am right now in File :

`\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider.php`

**Function : validateCredentials**

There is below mentioned code

```
return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
```

I am trying to find out why the value of `$user->getAuthPassword()` is null and that's the reason I want to know the location for definition of this function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a very simple function in `Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable`.

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}
```

It'll fetch your user model's (hashed) password.

Comment: is there any tool to go to definition of the function in Laravel  5.1 ? +1

Comment: @Helper I just use my IDE's "find in folder" functionality on `vendor/laravel/framework`. I searched for `function getAuthPassword` and there it was. You could also search Github at https://github.com/laravel/framework, or search at http://laravel.com/api/5.1/ which'll give you the file and line as well.